# Outlook Bug Found using any addin

Tags: outlook, office-js, outlook-addin, outlook-web-addins

I am currently using Outlook Version

Microsoft® Outlook® for Microsoft 365 MSO (Version 2109 Build 16.0.14430.20154) 32-bit

Here's the Issue.

1. I have an email opened in Read Mode.
2. Sender: sender@senderemail.com  To: recipient@recipient.com
3. Open Any addin and Pin it
4. Click back on the email and the sender has been added to the To: list.
5. So it now lists the sender as a recipient.
6. Close the Addin
7. Reset the view by clicking on drafts, then go back to inbox.
8. Check the email in step 2 and it's back to normal.

Please help with this.

Comment: I've reproed this issue and opened a bug with the core team. I do not know when it will be addressed. Internal Bug Id #: 5494836

Comment: So simple... It is a product issue I suppose. But for any issues with add-ins I'd suggest posting bugs to the https://github.com/OfficeDev/office-js/issues repo.

Comment: This bug has the same root issue as: https://github.com/OfficeDev/office-js/issues/2170 The status of the fix will be updated there.

Comment: Thank you so much for responding so quickly.

Comment: We were able to send out an update to fix this bug. It should be live by now on all builds that had the issue. No updates/reinstallation of Outlook is necessary, but Outlook will need to be rebooted, and maybe the computer rebooted as well. An internet connection is also required for the update to work. 

If you are still seeing the issue, please let us know the build number, and delivery channel that you are on.

Comment: It works terrific thank you for responding so quickly on this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This bug has been resolved by MFST